# What does :: (double colon) mean in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

formal_list: typ ID { [($1,$2)] }
| formal_list COMMA typ ID { ($3,$4) :: $1 }

What does the `::` operator mean?
For instance: `a :: b`
Is the meaning that we add a to b?

Answer (score 6):

The `::` operator constructs a list. At the left is a list element (the head), at the right is a list (the tail). The operator is right associative, so you can write: `3 :: 4 :: []`. The empty list is denoted by `[]`.